# Iterate values in dataframe to print to Word using python-docx

Tags: python, pandas, loops, docx

I am working with a pandas dataframe that contains titles, sources, and links to various news articles sourced from the GoogleNews API. I have then categorized the data into the various keywords I used to find the articles. I am attempting to iterate through the 'keyword' column to print the data neatly, and then export the iterations to Word using python-docx.

To pull the GoogleNews data, I am using a for loop with various keywords set up in a list. It looks like:

```
for i in list:
    googlenews=GoogleNews()
    googlenews.get_news(i)
    googlenews.set_lang('en')
    googlenews.set_period('1d')
    result=googlenews.result()
    df_ivar = pd.DataFrame(result)
    df_ivar = df_ivar[df_ivar['date'].notna()]
    df_ivar = df_ivar[df_ivar["date"].str.contains('hours ago')] # to only pull articles from within the last 24 hours
    df_ivar = df_ivar[['site', 'title', 'desc', 'link']]
    df_ivar['keyword'] = i
    df = df_ivar.append(df, ignore_index=True)
```

So far, I have found a way to print the data correctly, but I cannot find a way to only show each keyword once, and then print all the article titles, descriptions, and links below their appropriate keywords.

My data currently looks like this:

```
article 1    link 1    description 1    keyword 1
article 2    link 2    description 2    keyword 1
article 3    link 3    description 3    keyword 2
article 4    link 4    description 4    keyword 3
```

Upon export, I would like the python-docx document to display the data categorically, such as:

```
keyword 1
article 1
article 2

keyword 2
article 3

keyword 3
article 4
```

I have the python-docx script in working order, but every time I print the document, I am stuck with the keyword being presented ahead of every article name, when I would simply like the keyword displayed once, and any relevant articles posted below it. Currently, my for loop looks like:

```
for i in df.index:
    document.add_heading(df['keyword'][i], level=1)
    p = document.add_paragraph().add_run(dfs['title'][i]).underline = True
    document.add_paragraph(df['desc'][i], style='List Bullet')
    document.add_paragraph(df['link'][i], style='List Bullet')
    document.add_paragraph('Source: ' + df['site'][i], style='List Bullet')
```

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Pandas [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) using the `keyword` as parameter. The return of this function will be the name of the group (the `keyword` in this particular case) and the `dataframe` for this keyword. You can then use the `name` for the `add_heading` function and use the remaining logic you already built, but iterating over the group variable (`for i in g.index`).

```py
for name, g in df.groupby('keyword'):
    document.add_heading(name, level=1)
    for i in g.index:
        p = document.add_paragraph().add_run(df['title'][i]).underline = True
        document.add_paragraph(df['desc'][i], style='List Bullet')
        document.add_paragraph(df['link'][i], style='List Bullet')
        document.add_paragraph('Source: ' + df['site'][i], style='List Bullet')
```

Comment: That is perfect and exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help.